# Using C++ stream for cout or text file

Tags: c++, stream, cout, ofstream, ostream

I have a very simple program where I ask the user if they want to print to screen or a file. Rather than create two sets of output sections, I thought I could switch a stream to either cout or an ofstream and then output to that stream. However, I'm getting screen output no matter what.

```
ostream &out = cout;

do
{
    cout << "Write to file (f) or screen (s)?";
    cin >> yes_or_no;
} while (yes_or_no != 'f' && yes_or_no !='s');

if (yes_or_no=='f')
{
    ofstream out;
    out.open("Report.txt");
    cout << "Writing report to Report.txt" << endl;
    system("pause");
}

out << "Day:        Current Value         ROI" << endl;
out << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
out << setw(5) << 0;
out << "$" << setw(20) << setprecision (2) << fixed << initial_value;
out << setw(12) << "1.00" << endl;
for (int day = 1 ; day < number_of_days ; day++)
{
    current_value = generateNextStockValue(current_value, volatility, trend);
    out << setw(5) << day;
    out << setw(20) << setprecision (2) << fixed << current_value;
    out << setw(12) << setprecision (2) << fixed << current_value / initial_value;
    out << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are writing to `cout`. Your `ofstream` is limited to the scope of the `if`.

Comment: @juanchopanza But I initialized "out" to ofstream and opened Report.txt.

Comment: Your declaration `ofstream out;` is in a smaller scope than the rest of the program.  The `ofstream` object `out` goes out of scope at the end of that `if` clause (closing brace).

Comment: I'm confused. If I have `int a = 1; if (5<6) {a = 10}; cout << a << endl;` I will will see 10, even though a is defined to 10 inside the scope of an if statement. Why does that not work with a stream?

Comment: That is completely different. You are instantiating a new `ostream` in the `if` block. Anyway, you cannot re-assign references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put all the writing logic inside a function, and let the caller decide which output stream to write to:

```
void do_the_stuff(std::ostream& os)
{
  // write to os
  os << "blah blah" ....
}
```

then

```
if (yes_or_no=='f')
{
  ofstream out("Report.txt");
  do_the_stuff(out);
} else {
  do_the_stuff(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to store it in a variable? I'd rather not wrap every call in an `if` if I can avoid it. I tried `=` and copy-constructing, but both have been deleted AFAICT